# Converting Image address into UIIMAGE but nothing shows up

Tags: swift

Im currently trying to convert a specific kind of image address into a uiimage. this is an example image address https://docs.watchsystems.com/pictures/55764/2312006-181.jpg but every time I run my code for some reason the image address is not turned into an image . Here is my code below. it keeps going to the else block which says err but im not sure what's the cause

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://docs.watchsystems.com/pictures/55764/2312006-181.jpg") else {
                return
            }

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let _data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: _data) {
                        // Display the image in an image view or do something else with it
                        self.imageOutlet.image = image
                        print(_data)
                    }else{
                        print("err")
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
```

Ive tried making subtle changes but usually this works for other image addresses but not for this one. Im not sure specifically what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should Allow Arbitrary Loads in App Transport Security Settings in your Info.plist. It seems like your https request gets redirected to some http resource, and ATS blocks the connection.

Second, the server returns 403 forbidden for some reason if the resource is requested from an app. You can see the error if you try this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://docs.watchsystems.com/pictures/55764/2312006-181.jpg") else {
    return
}
        
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let _data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }
            
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        print("Bad response")
        return
    }
            
    print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            
    if let string = String(data: _data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(string)
    }
            
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let image = UIImage(data: _data) {
            // Display the image in an image view or do something else with it
            self.imageView.image = image
            print(_data)
        } else {
            print("err")
        }
    }
}
        
task.resume()
```

The html code returned by the request appears to be a 1020 Cloudflare error. This error is related with firewall settings of the website. So, contact to the website admins, if you can, or try to load another image.

Comment: thank you for your response I kind of assumed it might be forbidden but you confirmed it for me